# Drupal 7 : How can see number views of node

Tags: drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7. After enabling the Statistics module, I see, under each node, how many times it has been read (e.g. "4 reads").

I need to knew where this views (e.g. "4 reads") save in table in database ?

I need to know where is saved to using it in my SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data is stored in database table **node_counter**, field **totalcount**.

You can use function [statistics_get()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21statistics%21statistics.module/function/statistics_get/7) to get the total number of times the node has been viewed.

Example:

```
// the node nid
$nid = 1;
// get the node statistics
$node_stats = statistics_get($nid);
// get the count of the node reads
$node_reads = $node_stats['totalcount'];
```

Or, if you need to access it directly with SQL code,

```
SELECT totalcount FROM node_counter WHERE nid = 1;
```